Using multiple variables in polynom package
I currently have to work with a lot of polynomials. Thus I have to do some polynomial division. Sadly I did not find any documentation of multi-variable polynomial division in the polynom package. Is there a way to do it or do I have to change my approach and use another package for example?
Polynomial in question:
x^3+(a^2-2a+1)*x^2+(-2a^3+a^2-2a)*x-2a^3 divided by {x+1}
\polylongdiv[vars=x,a]{x^3+(a^2-2a+1)*x^2+(-2a^3+a^2-2a)*x-2a^3}{x+1}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Style B:}\par
\polylongdiv[style=B]{2x^3-0x^2+0x-16}{x-2}

---------------------------------------------------

\polylongdiv[vars=x,a]{x^3+(a^2-2a+1)*x^2+(-2a^3+a^2-2a)*x-2a^3}{x+1}

\end{document}

I am using Overleaf to convert into pdf. When compiling it compiles for about 5 min then times out. I have tried finding the error via stop on first error, then the error message "Package keyval Error: a undefined." comes up.

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Is [vars=xa] what you are looking for?

No, I want them to be their own variable. Basically it should be a function of x but with the changing variable of a

[vars=xa] is the correct way to indicate that both a and x are variables (see the manual, section 4.1 \polyset{hkey=value listi}). Could you precise the expected result? polynom can handle parameters, for example \polylongdiv{x^3+(2a+1)x^2+(2a+3)x+3}{x+1} works. Anyway, there is a warning in its documentation: Please note that this is work in progress. Multivariate polynomials
are currently not supported.

yes your division is working, however when I use either vars as a key in \polyset or in \polylongdiv the operation breaks. When compiled without the key yours is working fine, but mine is just taking forever to compile. Tho thanks for the help jlab.

Edit: I expect the result to be x^2+x(a^2-2a)-2a^3.
